# FBX export from 3DS Max 2017

Tags: export, .fbx

I am trying to export a 3dsmax model to Blender and the position/orientation of some objects is completely wrong as per this screenshot.

The exported fbx looks all right in any fbx viewer I tried and I played around with the fbx import options (apply transform, use pre/post rotation) but always the same result.

It seems like only the items that were created with some sort of symmetry are affected (not the original author of the model so it's only a guess) anybody have a tip/hint as to where this is coming from?

I'm using Blender 2.78a and FBX 2014/2015 binary, not that it matters, since I tried all the other formats for the export and it's still doing the same thing.

[image]

Thanks a million in advance I ran out of hair to pull on this one.

Comment: I see there are some keframes in whatever object is currently selected. Maybe it is actually an issue with animation instead?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this. i removed all animations from the export and it's still doing it... actually when i exported the model in ascii and went to check the coordinates they seem to match (as in one door would be at x,y,z and the mirror door on the other side at -x,y,z ... but the net result is one at the right place and the other way off) ... puzzling

Comment: FBX is vast and far reaching format with many variables, hidden tricks, and different implementations. Getting a full perfect export is often hard I suspect. My humble advice is that you are probably better off fixing what looks like just a few bad cases by hand, then wasting time getting it to export as intended

Comment: Again a couple years late, but I answered this over here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299211/172273